# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE proper use

Tags: php, mysql, insert, duplicates, key

I have read dozens of threads on here regarding this and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm on my second day of learning PHP.

My script uses`INSERT INTO` to put data in my database and it works until I enter a duplicate key. I would like my script to insert data into the non-unique table fields, in that case, and ignore the key columns. I'm trying to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for this. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Here is part of the script:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO modelSpecificVoicecoil (speakerModelNo, manufacturer, voicecoilModelNo) 
VALUES ('$_POST[speakerModelNo]','$_POST[manufacturer]','$_POST[voicecoilModelNo]')";
```

---

The columns `speakerModelNo` and `manufacturer` make a compound key. Using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` gives me many different errors depending on how I write it and on what line I write it. Again, I'm not using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to try and update the fields in the key columns. I get syntax errors and parsing errors.

Thank you. I hope I'm being clear enough.

Comment: Please post the statement that's actually using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. I think you would just want something like this: `$sql="INSERT INTO modelSpecificVoicecoil (speakerModelNo, manufacturer, voicecoilModelNo) 
VALUES ('$_POST[speakerModelNo]','$_POST[manufacturer]','$_POST[voicecoilModelNo]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE voicecoilModelNo='$_POST[voicecoilModelNo]'";`

Comment: @DavidWinder Yes! That does do exactly what I was trying to achieve. I had written it similarly to how you wrote it except I made a mistake with my usage of quotes and the semicolon. I would post an example but I have not figured out this markdown formatting thing yet. Thank you, you not only solved my problem but I also learned the next subject I need to read about.

Comment: @Bret.burrill glad I could help